# C++ prevent ambiguous parameter int vs int&

Tags: c++, qt

I specalized `QApplication` as `MyApplication` taking an `int` parameter for construction.

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    Foo( int argc, char **argv ) : QApplication( argc, argv )
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

This class is again specialized in many places in my code.

Unfortunately, I used `int`, while I should have used `int&` (as `Qapplication` expects). Under Windows it did not cause any trouble, but when I moved to Linux it started crashing. So I changed `MyApplication` to:

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    Foo( int& argc, char **argv ) : QApplication( argc, argv )
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

But then, all classes specializing `MyApplication` also need to be updated, and there are many of them, if they are not, code still compiles but is likely to crash.

**I need to identify all places where the change should be applied, but I also want to prevent new code from doing the same mistake.**

Is there any way/trick to prevent specialization with `int` instead of `int&' to compile?

I'd like this code not to be permitted and to produce compilation error:

```
class OtherApplication : public MyApplication 
{
public:
    Foo( int argc, char **argv ) : MyApplication( argc, argv )
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to bite the bullet and update everything to use references, at the moment you are taking a reference to a temporary which is a really bad MSVC extension, QT holds on to the reference and will update its value: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#QApplication. Maybe you just got lucky that it didn't already crash horribly

Comment: `static_assert()` in a compile-time loop over the types?

Comment: When you say there are many subclasses, how many are you talking about, and are you in control of all these? As in, this is all your code and not some publicly-released API? Because you'll be surprised how quickly you can fix them all with some careful regex and a "replace in files" operation. I'd be willing to bet that the _only_ place that `int argc` appears in your code is in this situation.

Comment: @paddy: I can fix them all, but I'm more scared about new code that could reintroduce the problem.

Comment: @JasonLiam: I'm using Visual Studio 2022, no extension enabled. This compiles not even with a warning.

Comment: @JasonLiam that's no temporary there, it is a variable with automatic storage duration. There is no error requested by the compiler in this situation.

Comment: It seems excessive to worry about new code adding back the issue, when all other code demonstrates the correct way. It's quite common when writing something new to copy/paste an existing one as a starter, then gut it and rename stuff. But if you're really worried, then don't use those parameters at all. Instead, write a simple wrapper for them that encapsulates the reference and array parameter, and make that your constructor's parameter. This will depart from the Qt style, in that your class no longer looks like a `QApplication` subclass, but you'll prevent this one scenario.

Comment: @paddy: I like that, it's a good idea. I'll pass a "MainParam" object encapsualting the `int& argc`, `char **argv` as attributes, this will force specialized class to handle that correctly. I suggest that you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to wrap the parameters in your own structure and pass that. This forces subclass construction to use that signature.

It also allows more flexibility if for whatever reason you ever want to add additional stuff to the constructor without going and modifying everything. This technique is used in some APIs to avoid breaking function signatures with minor changes.

I've shown this inline for simplicity, but you could of course hide the implementation if you want.

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    struct Args final
    {
        Args(int& argc, char** argv) : argc(argc) , argv(argv) {}
        int& argc;
        char** argv;
    };

    MyApplication(const Args& args)
        : QApplication(args.argc, args.argv)
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyApplication myapp({argc, argv});

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Jakob Stark answer also works but maybe this one is more "elegant".

Answer (score 5):

To summarize your question: you need to make a change to a signature of a function (in this case a constructor) and everywhere it is used it's necessary to make a corresponding change, of some sort, but the signature change won't always result in a compilation failure every time, that you can pull up and fix, and move to the next one.

The solution is to have a guaranteed compilation failure:

```
MyApplication( int &argc, char **argv, int ignore ) : QApplication( argc, argv )
```

Now you're guaranteed to have a compilation failure due to a missing parameter.

As part of fixing every guaranteed compilation failure you'll also add a dummy 0 parameter.

Once all compilation failures get fixed, and the code compiles, you're now going to go back and remove the dummy parameter. Yes, you'll get to have another round of fixing every compilation failure. But each one's trivial, just remove the extra `0` parameter, and this approach guaranteed a proper update to every existing usage of the original constructor.

Comment: Thanks, thta's what I considered in the first place. But it does not prevent someone to later create a new class with `int` and re-introduce the problem without getting any compilation warning/error. As it only crashs in Release today, the problem can easily be introduced during development.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a pointer to `argc` like this:

```
MyApplication(int *argc, char **argv): QApplication(*argc, argv)
```

That way you force the 'pass by reference' semantic explicitely. Of course you will still need to change all the derived classes, but you will get compilation errors, if you don't. A derived class constructor like

```
OtherApplication(int argc, char **argv): MyApplication(argc, argv)
```

will fail to compile and even forces someone who later creates a new derivated class to think about the problem.

Comment: That's actually a very nice way to fix the issue. As passing `int` as `int*` leads to compilation error unlinke passing `int` as `int&` which works with no error/warning. Then we force caller to dereference main's `int` parameter before calling the application constructor (it also highlight the fact that `QApplication` may modify it).